# How to convert the data frame values and its headers into a list with python?

Tags: python, sql-server, python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to convert one data frame into a list and I want to keep the header names but I am unable to achieve this.

I am downloading the data from a SQL database and then I convert this data into a data frame:

```
import pypyodbc
from datetime import datetime

initial_date = datetime(2017,1,1,00,00,00)
end_date     = datetime(2017,6,1,00,00,00)

sql_connection = pypyodbc.connect(driver="{SQL Server}", server="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx", uid="you-dont-know-me",
                                       pwd="guess...", Trusted_Connection="No")
#execute the SP to retrieve data
retrieve_database_values = "[DEV].[SP].[QA_ExportV2] @start_date='{start_date:%Y-%m-%d}', " \
                     "@end_date='{end_date:%Y-%m-%d'}".format(start_date=initial_date, end_date=end_date)

df = pd.read_sql_query(retrieve_database_values, sql_connection)
```

Then the way I convert this data frame into lists is with the following code:

```
df.values.tolist()
```

Which gives me the results:

```
[[100008115, 'CAS.Santa', 'CAS.Santa-2', 'Yes', 'Transferred', Timestamp('2017-03-11 08:15:00'), ...],
[100008116, 'Springfield', 'Springfield:H3', 'Yes','Traffic Variation', Timestamp('2017-09-11 00:00:00'), ...],
[...],[...]]
```

However, I want to be able to retrieve the data values and the header names of the data frame, something like this:

```
[['id', 100008115, 'site','CAS.Santa', 'site name','CAS.Santa-2', 'new','Yes', 'status','Transferred', 'initial date' ,Timestamp('2017-03-11 08:15:00'), ...],
['id',100008116, 'site','Springfield', 'site name','Springfield:H3', 'new','Yes', 'status','Traffic Variation', 'initial date' ,Timestamp('2017-09-11 00:00:00'), ...],
[...],[...]]
```

or if possible something like this:

```
[[('id', 100008115), ('site','CAS.Santa'), ('site name','CAS.Santa-2'), ('new','Yes'), ('status','Transferred'), ('initial date' ,Timestamp('2017-03-11 08:15:00')), (...)],
[('id',100008116), ('site','Springfield'), ('site name','Springfield:H3'), ('new','Yes'), ('status','Traffic Variation'), ('initial date' ,Timestamp('2017-09-11 00:00:00')), (...)],
[...],[...]]
```

Comment: Did you look through the documentation to see if there was something that might help?

Comment: There is this `df.columns.values.tolist()` but it throws me the column values, that is, `[id,site, site name, new,...]`not the desired result that I want.

Comment: Looks like you want something similar to key-value pairs.

Comment: Yes, something like a list that contains tuples with key and value.

Comment: Are you you using the DataFrame for anything else or is it just an intermediate step to get your desired result?

Comment: Data frame is just an intermediate step to achieve my desired result. Your solution worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One of the options of [DataFrame.to_dict()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_dict.html) should work.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1, 2, 3], 'b':[2, 3, 3]})

>>> df
   a  b
0  1  2
1  2  3
2  3  3
>>>
>>> df.to_dict('records')
[{'a': 1, 'b': 2}, {'a': 2, 'b': 3}, {'a': 3, 'b': 3}]

>>> result = df.to_dict('records')
>>> for thing in result:
...     print(list(thing.items()))


[('a', 1), ('b', 2)]
[('a', 2), ('b', 3)]
[('a', 3), ('b', 3)]
>>>
```

---

> Data frame is just an intermediate step to achieve my desired result.

Seems like you could get your result directly from the output of the stored procedure. I have no way to test this but looking through the [pypyodbc wiki](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki)
I came up with this alternative to the DataFrame...

Create a cursor from your connection object

```
cursor = sql_connection.cursor()
```

Reformat the [stored procedure call](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Calling-Stored-Procedures) and execute it

```
sp = "{{CALL {}}}".format(retrieve_database_values)
cursor.execute(sp)
```

Then from method three of the the nice [Hello World script](https://github.com/jiangwen365/pypyodbc/wiki/A-Hello-World-script-of-pypyodbc)

```
query_results = [dict(zip([column[0] for column in cursor.description], row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
```

`query_results` should be a list of dicts like `result` from my DataFrame.to_dict() solution.

If I am reading that comprehension correctly, `zip` produces tuples so I think what you want is

```
query_results = [list(zip([column[0] for column in cursor.description], row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]
#OR
query_results = []
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    column_names = [column[0] for column in cursor.description]
    query_results.append(list(zip(column_names, row)))
```

I imagine that could be refined.

Comment: Not An Answer :)

Comment: I tried all the methods that you provided me just today and I wanted to implement the `query_results = [list(zip([column[0] for column in cursor.description], row)) for row in cursor.fetchall()]` in production but seems like the solution `df.to_dict()`  will stick into our final product because I immediately used the following code to get all the ids with `id = [li['id'] for li in df.to_dict('records')]`. The complete solution that you provide with all the different possibilities is complete and I wish this answer could receive more points.